# How to do a log transformation on more than one attribute(column) - Python

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn, normalization, transformation

I have a dataset with 2 columns that are on a completely different scales.

I need to do a log transformation on both columns to be able to do some visualization on them.

I cannot find a code for python that allows me to do the log transformation on several columns.

Can anybody help me?

I have a dataset with Qualitative and Quantitative columns and I wish to do the log on The RealizedPL and Volume columns.

My dataset looks a bit like this:

```
     Date           Name       Country     Product     RealizedPL     Volume
0    2019.01.01     Charles    Country1    ProductA      100           10200
1    2019.02.20     Pierre     Country2    ProductB      150           20500
2    2019.03.02     Chiara     Country1    ProductA      200           15300
```

How can I do the log transformation and keep the other columns as well? Either by creating new columns for the log or directly replacing the columns with the log.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may wish to try:

```
df[["RealizedPL","Volume"]] = df[["RealizedPL","Volume"]].apply(np.log)
print(df)
         Date     Name   Country   Product  RealizedPL    Volume
0  2019.01.01  Charles  Country1  ProductA    4.605170  9.230143
1  2019.02.20   Pierre  Country2  ProductB    5.010635  9.928180
2  2019.03.02   Chiara  Country1  ProductA    5.298317  9.635608
```

or:

```
df[["RealizedPL_log", "Volume_log"]] = df[["RealizedPL","Volume"]].apply(np.log)
```

to have logs as separate columns.

Also note, if this is simply for visualization purposes, you may wish to try `df.plot.scatter(..., logx=True, logy=True)`.

Comment: What if I want to add the columns 'Log_RealizedPL' and 'Log_Volume' to the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FunctionTransformer` in scikit learn for this and just choose to which columns you want to apply the transformation. As a second step, you can just add these transformed columns to your original dataframe.

On a dummy example, it would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [3, 44, 2], "c": [4, 4, 3]})
transformer = FunctionTransformer(np.log)

df[["a_log", "b_log"]] = transformer.fit_transform(df[["a", "b"]])
```